# Make my machine open to internet through VPS

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, reverse-tunnel

So currently what I have as follow:

- Private IP
- A Windows local machine I have full access for
- An Amazon free-tier VPS that I have full access

So as you know the AWS Free Tier has a public IP on it, I have been using it for my development and testing. Now I want to add it to another level, I want to use my local machine as the server for me and my friends to play some MMORPG that I host.

I have confirmed the accessibility of the game server to be accessed through my local network. But now I have come across the problem on how to make my friend able to gain access through internet.

I have tried to do the reverse tunnel using ssh to my VPS and open the port to map to my local port. I can test with a simple ExpressJS server that forward the port 3000 on my VPS to my machine, both of us can see that my friend machine can connect to my machine.

But then here comes the problem: the MMORPG server usually comes with multiple instance of server, for example rAthena comes with Login, Chat, and Map server. The server comes with their own ports and it seems that I have to forward each the ports manually. Is there a way for me to forward multiple ports at once?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a vpn between your server (vpn client) and VPS (vpn server).  You may need to do port mapping on the vps to translate requests targetted at the vps to direct them down the VPN.